# upgrade some code to a newer version of jquery

Tags: jquery

i have some trouble with a plugin that work with an older version of jquery but not with newers :/

it's originally from this page
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/06/09/grid-navigation-effects/

after some debugging it seems that these lines are guilty :

```
var currentRows = '', nextRows = '';
                for( var i = 0; i < opts.rows; ++i ) {
                    currentRows += '.tj_row_' + (config.currentRow + i) + ',';

                    (dir === 1)
                        ? nextRows  += '.tj_row_' + (config.currentRow + opts.rows + i) + ','
                        : nextRows  += '.tj_row_' + (config.currentRow - 1 - i) + ',';
                }
```

the error in the console is

> jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   .tj_row_1,.tj_row_2,.tj_row_3,(…)

if i comment them i don't have the error in the console but the pluging don't work properly .

this lines of code are working perfectly in jquery 1.6.1 but not in 1.9.1

any idea on what's going on and how to fix that please ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery Migrate plugin when updated to 1.9.1, see details in https://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/